# Factors affecting the performance, safety and security of object-oriented programs?

Tags: oop

How does object oriented programming improve performance, safety and security of programs and what factors affect their performance and security.

Answer (score 0):

OOP doesn't improve performance *per se*. In fact, it has been a long criticism that OOP increased overall resource consumption. It was a trade-off between performance/optimization with productivity/maintainibility.

In terms of security, while procedural programs could be *secure*, the advent of OOP and increased reausability which comes in with it has spread reusable good coding practices. At the end of the day, a program that can be seamlessly maintained, built on top of reusable patterns and developed with good security practices should provide an easier foundation to detect and fix security holes.

In summary, OOP doesn't provide any direct advantage in the fields you're asking for but it provides a solid foundation to *code better* in most business cases. That's all.